# merge two partition with different disk in centos

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos

I have a lite centos 6 on my system. I am going to resize one of its partition. Here is the file system of this system:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_hadoop1-lv_root
                      5.5G  3.7G  1.6G  71% /
tmpfs                 937M     0  937M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   32M  428M   7% /boot
/dev/sdb1             5.0G  139M  4.6G   3% /disk1
cm_processes          937M     0  937M   0% /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process
```

I want to resize `/disk1` to 1G and resize `/` to 9.5G. But the problem is that `/` and `/disk1` are on two different devices! Is that possible to resize `/` without formatting that?

FYI, here is the output of fdisk -l :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1305 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0008d752

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64        1306     9972736   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 5368 MB, 5368709120 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 652 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8376205b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1         652     5237158+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_hadoop1-lv_root: 5981 MB, 5981077504 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 727 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_hadoop1-lv_swap: 4227 MB, 4227858432 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 514 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Output of vgscan:

```
Found volume group "vg_hadoop1" using metadata type lvm2
```

Also please be informed that this machine is located inside vmware esx as a guest OS, although I think this fact does not change the process.

Regards.

Comment: Can you additionally post the output of # /sbin/fdisk -l so we can see the filesystem for /disk1 and /dev/mapper/vg_hadoop1-lv_root?  It will change some of the commands you would run to perform your resizing

Comment: Also the output of # /sbin/vgscan will be helpful (needed) :) -- moderators: if anyone can edit my previous comment and add this to the first comment, and delete this one... that would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since / is on a Logical Volume, it is possible to *grow* /dev/mapper/vg_hadoop1-lv_root **without reformatting**.  This operation will be very safe, providing there is no lightning strike.

Because /dev/sdb1 (/disk1) is not a logical volume, it is *still possible* to shrink it -- however there are are **always possibilities of this failing**.  I have never personally had an issue with resizing a partition providing there was enough space; but that does not mean it's impsossible!  Many of the tools you could use to shrink a partition will warn you of this fact.  Once again, despite that: I haven't found anyone ever having issues doing so.

Now, if you either have /disk1 backed up, or don't mind it being lost, continue!

---

So, for us to continue the data pivot, we will first shrink /disk1, so we later have enough space to grow /.  First, we must ensure it is unmounted -- you can't (safely) shrink a mounted volume.

```
# umount /dev/sdb1
```

### Tools

[note for other readers: this only works with ext{2,3,4} filesystems]
We can either use *resize2fs* + *fdisk*, or *gparted*.  fdisk is not for the faint of heart.  If you would like to use a GUI to shrink your partition, you can follow this guide: http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-resize-partition ,

First, let's resize the boundaries (partition) to make sure no data is at the end of our partition.

```
# resize2fs /dev/sdb1 1G
```

Now, for fdisk we can do:

```
# fdisk /dev/sdb
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help):
```

Remember, partitions are just boundaries for data.  Deleting a partition won't delete the underlying data.  They're like pointers in a non-garbage collected programming language.  Luckily, with your output from fdisk -l, we have the boundaries (pointer locations) for your partition!

**This is where there is a possibility of losing data.  I am not responsible for you deleting very important things off of /disk1 without you having backed it up.  Backup anything you need to two locations before performing this step**

Let's delete your partition

```
Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1-4, default 4): 1
Partition 1 is deleted

Command (m for help):
```

And recreate it with the (reduced) boundaries

```
Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended
Select (default e): p
Selected partition 1
First sector (1-5368, default 1): <hit enter>
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2-5368, default 5368): +1G
Partition 1 of type Linux and of size 1 GiB is set

Command (m for help):
```

And then, we'll create another partition that we can use later with all of our new free space we made

```
Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended
Select (default e): p
Selected partition 2
First sector (1025-5368, default 1025): <hit enter>
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (1026-5368, default 5368): <hit enter>
Partition 2 of type Linux and of size <remaining> is set

Command (m for help):
```

Our new partitions are setup, and we can continue to the next step

---

Cool!  The hard part is done.  Your question is one of the awesome features of LVM, and why it is so often used (merging partitions, even on separate drives!)

So, what we are trying to do is *grow the logical volume* which is /dev/mapper/vg_hadoop1-lv_root.  To do that, we need enough space in our **volume group** to grow!  We can do this by adding a *physical volume* to our *volume group*.

So, we will first create a *Physical Volume* out of our new partition, so it can be recognized by LVM, and later added to a *volume group*.  We do this with...

```
# /sbin/pvcreate /dev/sdb2
```

LVM can add any Physical Volumes to any Volume Groups, so we'll add it to our hadoop one, which we found from the output of

```
# /sbin/vgscan
```

So, we know we want vg_hadoop1.  We'll add our new physical volume to this volume group with...

```
# /sbin/vgextend vg_hadoop1 /dev/sdb2
```

Now that it's added, we run a quick command to resize the current logical volume

```
# /sbin/lvextend -L +4.0G /dev/mapper/vg_hadoop1-lv_root
```

---

the -L parameter to lvextend is pretty cool, and can take a variety of different input.  We are using + almost like the += binary operator in many programming languages.  We're saying "new size = current size + 4.5G"

Now that that's all said and done, we have two filesystems that are not the same size as the volume they are residing on.  For an ext2/3/4fs filesystem [most common] (which I will update the question once we have the output of fdisk -l to tell us what filesystem you're using), we can change the filesystem to match the partition size with:

```
# /sbin/resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_hadoop1-lv_root
# /sbin/resize2fs /dev/sdb1
```

You may need to remount root to see the new size.  We might as well also mount /disk1 back again. do this with:

```
# mount -o remount /
# mount /dev/sdb1 /disk1
```

Let's make sure everything worked, by using df (disk free), and that everything is the right size.

```
# df -H
```

Once I get the output of those two commands, I'll update this question so you can be doubly sure everything is correct before running through.

Good luck!

Comment: Please check the main question, I added your require information.

Comment: Thanks!  I threw your information in @Ali n.  I may have had some off-by-one errors.  Please let me know if the numbers deviate from what you see anywhere.  Also vmware should not conflict with what we are doing; you should be fine if it was either a hard machine, or a virtual machine.

Comment: It was perfect, works for me.